# Translating a sentence from one of Hilbert's papers

Tags: geometry, translation-request, mathematical-german

I'm trying to translate one of Hilbert's papers. I'm 90% done, but I am stuck on one sentence, as my German is very poor and the sentence is involved. I hope someone can give me a rough\quick translation of the following lengthy sentence fragment. Thanks!

> Sind nämlich irgend 2 in einer Ebene alpha gelegene und in einem Punkte C sich schneidende Geraden a und b der ursprünglichen Geometrie gegeben, so werden im Allgemeinen in jedem der 4 in alpha um C herum entstehenden ebenen Winkelräume solche gerade Linien vorhanden sein, welche keine der 
>   beiden Geraden a und b schneiden; sind jedoch insbesondere in 2 sich
>   gegenüberliegenden ebenen Winkelräumen keine solchen geraden Linien vorhandend, so ist die fragliche Bedingung erfült;

Thanks again!

Comment: This is not a translation site though your material may pertain to Mathematics

Comment: Umm....use Google Translate??!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I tried Google translate. Usually with the help of Goggle translate I  can figure out the correct translation. But the requested sentence has me beaten.

Comment: FYI, all request that need translation of mathematical material should be tagged with 'translation-request'.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up for the tag "translation-request". I didn't see that tag. I need the translation for a mathematics research article I'm working on.

Comment: @Shailesh: Such questions have been asked and answered here before; some of us are quite happy to answer them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. thanks for pointing it out. I stand corrected and apologies

Comment: @Shailesh: That’s okay.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence says something like this: If $a$ and $b$ are any two lines in the plane $\alpha$ with cutting point $C$ with respect to the original geometry, then, in general, there will exist lines in any of the 4 angle spaces around $C$, that will neither intersect $a$ nor $b$; if on the other hand there are no such lines in 2 opposite angle spaces, then the condition in question is satisfied.

Here, an "angle space" seems to be any one of the connected components of "$\alpha$ minus the union of $a$ and $b$".

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect!! :-)    Chris

Comment: Much is lost in translation from German, a more elegant language than English. The original text says more poetically "..are in fact  whatever two in a plane alpha laid and intersecting in C lines a and b of the original geometry given..." Mark Twain has already given us [his interesting remarks on the German language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "A more elegant language" is a controversial remark...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for the beautiful, literal translation.

Comment: Dear @Chris: I am happy to see that some users here appreciate beautiful English.